# Convert DB2 into Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, database-partitioning

I am getting error when try to run the query with Postgres

```
ALTER TABLE EMP.USER DETACH PARTITION ID_CUST_111111 INTO DATA_PRTTN.ID_CUST_111111_USER
```

> Wrapped by: java.sql.SQLException: SQL: ERROR: syntax error at or near "INTO"

Comment: Yes, that's incorrect. Remove the `INTO DATA_PRTTN.ID_CUST_111111_USER` and it will be correct. If it does what you want is a different question that we cannot answer without more information.

Comment: Actually the ID_CUST_111111 data partition is detached from table USER  and placed in table DATA_PRTTN.ID_CUST_111111_USER.How we placed into table in PostgreSQL

Comment: Did you check the manual? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't place a partition in a table in PostgreSQL. A partition already *is* a table. So simply remove the `INTO table_name` from the statement. You can rename the partition after detaching, but I don't see much sense in that.